# how to define multi-project build with sbt-native-packager that creates an RPM for each sub-project

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

In all of the examples I've seen regarding multi-module builds and sbt-native-packager, they all aggregate the sub-projects into a single package.  I have sub-projects that each provide a micro-service.  I believe that each of these should have it's own native package, but I don't see how to do that and have a one command build for all of the sub-projects.

Answer (score 4):

This turns out be straightforward.  Simply provide native-packager settings for each of the sub-projects that you want to package and don't provide any on the aggregating project.

I tested by modifying https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/multi-module-build accordingly:

```scala
import NativePackagerKeys._

name := "mukis-fullstack"

// used like the groupId in maven
organization in ThisBuild := "de.mukis"

// all sub projects have the same version
version in ThisBuild := "1.0"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.2"

// common dependencies
libraryDependencies in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0"
)

// this is the root project, aggregating all sub projects
lazy val root = Project(
    id = "root",
    base = file("."),
    // configure your native packaging settings here
//    settings = packageArchetype.java_server++ Seq(
//        maintainer := "John Smith <john.smith@example.com>",
//        packageDescription := "Fullstack Application",
//        packageSummary := "Fullstack Application",
        // entrypoint
//        mainClass in Compile := Some("de.mukis.frontend.ProductionServer")
//    ),
    // always run all commands on each sub project
    aggregate = Seq(frontend, backend, api)
) dependsOn(frontend, backend, api) // this does the actual aggregation

// --------- Project Frontend ------------------
lazy val frontend = Project(
    id = "frontend",
    base = file("frontend"),
    settings = packageArchetype.java_server++ Seq(
       maintainer := "John Smith <john.smith@example.com>",
       packageDescription := "Frontend appplication",
       mainClass in Compile := Some("de.mukis.frontend.ProductionServer")
    )
) dependsOn(api)


// --------- Project Backend ----------------
lazy val backend = Project(
    id = "backend",
    base = file("backend"),
    settings = packageArchetype.java_server++ Seq(
        maintainer := "John Smith <john.smith@example.com>",
        packageDescription := "Fullstack Application",
        packageSummary := "Fullstack Application",
        // entrypoint
        mainClass in Compile := Some("de.mukis.frontend.ProductionServer")
    )
) dependsOn(api)

// --------- Project API ------------------
lazy val api = Project(
    id = "api",
    base = file("api")
```

Results:

```
debian:packageBin
...misc messages elided...
[info] dpkg-deb: building package `frontend' in `../frontend_1.0_all.deb'.
[info] dpkg-deb: building package `backend' in `../backend_1.0_all.deb'.
```

Comment: Looks like `packageArchetype.java_server` is deprecated, I think an up-to-date API would be to instead call `.enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)` on the aggregated modules that we want packaged individually.

Answer (score 3):

For whom just ended up here, a more up-to-date answer could look like:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .aggregate(common, frontend, backend)

lazy val common = (project in file("common"))
lazy val frontend = (project in file("frontend"))
   .enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
lazy val backend = (project in file("backend"))
   .dependsOn(common)
   .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
   .settings(javaPackagingSettings)

lazy val javaPackagingSettings = Seq(
   // follow sbt-native-packager to identify settings you need
)
```

**Description**

Here is the scenario supporting the above configuration

- Project `root` is the parent and we don't want to package it. It aggregates other subprojects.
- Project `common` is a sort of library and also we don't want to package it
- Project `backend` depends on `common` for the libraries.
- Project `frontend` is a standalone project packaged as a Java server app with default configuration

Comment: It just works :) I'm baffled I found this on SO and not on [sbt-native-packager's docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/).